# PyCharm resolving - flask.ext.sqlalchemy vs flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

If I use the following format in my application, everything works, except PyCharms resolving / autocomplete feature:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

If I use the following format in my application, everything works. But, alas, it is not the correct way to import the libraries:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Is there any way to make PyCharm resolve the first syntax correctly?

Comment: `flask_sqlalchemy` is real package that make alias `flask.ext.sqlalchemy` - so it will work fine as just package. For me it work fine:
PyCharm 3.4.1.
Build #PY-135.1057, built on June 10, 2014
JRE: 1.7.0_65-b32 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation.
Probably you have local bug with environment.

Comment: Actually, `from flask_sqlalchemy import ..` is the correct form; the `flask.ext` alias scheme is deprecated: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/#ext-import-transition

Comment: `flaskext` is, not `.ext`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `flask.ext` namespace is a *transistion* namespace, see the [*Extension Import Transition* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensiondev/#ext-import-transition) of the *Flask Extension Development* docs:

> For a while we recommended using namespace packages for Flask extensions. This turned out to be problematic in practice because many different competing namespace package systems exist and pip would automatically switch between different systems and this caused a lot of problems for users.

and

> Flask extensions should urge users to import from `flask.ext.foo` instead of `flask_foo` or `flaskext_foo` **so that extensions can transition to the new package name** without affecting users.

So to *transition* between versions, the `flask.ext` alias was added, which will automatically try to import `flask_[name]` packages when importing `flask.ext.[name]`. But that transition is now moot; you no longer will find packages that still rely solely on `flask.ext`.

As such, it is *perfectly fine* to use the actual module name and have PyCharm autocomplete the module contents.

You only really *have* to use `flask.ext` if you are still using an older version of the extension and need to be future compatible. That future is already here.

Comment: Concise and straight to the point, saved me a lot of hassle :-)

Answer (score 11):

FYI. `flask.ext` is deprecated, and the right way is:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

In case anyone found this SO question on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtualenv and set that virtualenv for your project in PyCharm. I had the same problem as you do and after setting the correct virtualenv (which contains the flask and flask_sqlalchemy extension) my problem is solved.

To set a virtualenv for your project in PyCharm ([from JetBrains Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html)):

> To add an existing virtual environment to the list of available
>   interpreters
>       In the Project Interpreter page of the project settings, click [image].
>       In the drop-down list, choose Add local.
>
> [image]
>
> In the Select Python Interpreter dialog box that opens, 
>   choose the desired Python executable, and click OK.

Moreover try adding *requirements.txt* to the root of your project, afterward PyCharm will notify you to install missing dependencies which might help.