# Difference between flask.ext.openid and flask_openid?

Tags: python, import, flask

I'm creating a website using the (awesome!) [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework, and for this I occasionally use extensions. In the tutorials it always says you need to import them using something like this (in the case of openid):

```
from flask.ext.openid import OpenId
```

but I always use the following:

```
from flask_openid import OpenID
```

Is there any difference between the two? And if yes; which one is better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flask.ext` was [not recommended](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/1085#issuecomment-45466907) except during an API transition in the past and was deprecated. It is removed in Flask 1.0. Use the real import name, `flask_{name}`, instead.

Comment: Following the link to the supposed "duplicate" (here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25558257/1650012), I found an answer there which among some other things says: "[...] you no longer will find packages that still rely solely on flask.ext. As such, it is perfectly fine to use the actual module name and have PyCharm autocomplete the module contents. You only really have to use flask.ext if you are still using an older version of the extension and need to be future compatible. That future is already here." Does that mean using flask_foo is now fine?

Comment: Well, you seems right @kramer65 so you can use flask_foo instead of flask.ext :)